# Why do Object Permissions in Permission Set override Field Permissions in this case?

Tags: profile, permission-sets, field-level-security

I'm having an issue where I want a user with an assigned permission set to be able to see fields in an object ("Read" Permission in Object Level), but I want 2 fields to be hidden ("Launch URL" and "Operation"). At a profile level, this object has no permission access, so with the permission set I'm allowing certain users to view the object/fields, but I want to hide the two that I just mentioned:

[image]

However, when I go to record detail page, I still see these fields after logging in to Salesforce with the user that has the permission set assigned. Any ideas why these fields could not be hiding?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, @bonzi, welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. Could you please share the details of the permission set? I also recommend you to look at [Control Access to Objects at TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects). The latter may already answer your question.

Comment: Hello @JefersonChaves, thanks for your reply! What information regarding the permission set do you need? I have completed that Trailhead already, I also went over it but I can't see what I'm missing. Regards!

Comment: Sure thing, I believe the "Field Permissions" screenshot related to the profile, what about the Permission Sets assigned to the user in question? Can you please share the screenshot of the "Field Permissions" of permission sets assigned to the user?

Comment: Hello, the screenshot I posted is from the permission set. I have updated the image in the opening question.

Comment: Ok, the question then is: what about the user profile? Does it grant access? In salesforce, you can usually grant more access, not revoke after granted.

Comment: Hey @JefersonChaves, in my opening question I mention that at a profile level, this object has no permission access.

Comment: My bad, got it, @bonzi.

Comment: You say there are no object-level permissions in the profile, but have you cleared the field-level permissions in the profile also?

Comment: and you've checked that user's other permission sets don't grant read permission on those two fields? and that user's profile/permission sets don't include `View All Data`

Comment: @DavidCheng that was it! I had no object-level permissions in the profile but the field-level permissions were there, so that's what caused it. Thanks a lot to you and everyone for your input! :)

Comment: Hey, @DavidCheng, I suggest you submit this as an answer. I would vote and might be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are field-level permissions in a profile, these will take effect as soon as you assign object-level permissions in a permission set.  Thus,  you'll need to clear the object's FLS settings in the profile even if you've disabled all object-level permissions.